# sencha can't fire my label show event in controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i encounter a problem ,beacuse i can't fire my controller function in  my view as it's just a alert demo.

my controller:

```
Ext.define('ylp2p.controller.viewdata',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        control: {
            viewlabel: {
                show: 'viewlabelFn'
            }
        },        
        refs: {
            viewlabel: 'label[id=datalabel]',
        }
    },    
    viewlabelFn: function(){
        alert('painted');
    }
});
```

my view:

```
Ext.define('ylp2p.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
        'ylp2p.store.datainterests',
    ],
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        items: [
            {
                title: '首页',
                iconCls: 'home',
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                scrollable: true,
                layout: 'card',
                items:  [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'ylp2p'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype: 'carousel',
                            height: 300,
                            items: [
                            {
                                html: 'html1',
                                style: 'background-color:#5E99CC'
                            },
                            {
                                html: 'html2',
                                style: 'background-color: #759E60'
                            },
                            {
                                html: 'html3',
                            }
                            ]
                        },//end carousel
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            id: 'datalabel',
                            //tpl:  '{store.get("data")},{store.get("earn")}',
                            store: 'interestsdata',
                            //tpl: ['总投资:{data},盈利:{earn}'],
                            html: 'hello',
                            flex: 1,
                        }//end label
                    ]
                }
                ]//end items
            },
            {
                title: '融资',
                iconCls: 'locate',
                //xtype: 'makemoney'
            },
            {
                title: '理财',
                iconCls: 'action',
                //xtype: 'money'
            },
            {
                title: '账户',
                iconCls: 'user',
                //xtype: 'user'
            },
            {
                title: '更多',
                iconCls: 'more',
                //xtype: 'more'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the view instantiated? Try adding `requires: ['ylp2p.view.Main']` to the controller..

Comment: sorry,after i add it.still not work?THX Too~~

Comment: Do you have any errors or warnings in your console? Can you create a Sencha Fiddle for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    itemId: 'datalabel',
    //tpl:  '{store.get("data")},{store.get("earn")}',
    store: 'interestsdata',
    //tpl: ['总投资:{data},盈利:{earn}'],
    html: 'hello',
    flex: 1,
}
```

and select like this

```
Ext.define('ylp2p.controller.viewdata',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        control: {
            viewlabel: {
                show: 'viewlabelFn'
            }
        },        
        refs: {
            viewlabel: '#datalabel',
        }
    },    
    viewlabelFn: function(){
        alert('painted');
    },

    launch: function() {
        this.getViewlabel().show();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.getViewlabel()` if you call it from the `launch` event in the controller. You have to add `launch: function() {}` off course :)

Comment: yes!if i add this.getViewlabel().setHtml('yes') in launch event,it work!,but why it not work in my show event function..  :0

Comment: So now we tested that your ref selector is correct. I updated my answer and changed the listener from a listener on `show` to a listener on `painted`. The show event is only called when the label is shown by using the `show method`. In the docs for Sencha Touch this is not very clear, but in the docs for ExtJs it is: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Label-event-show

Comment: THX,haha!though it's not my expection

Comment: I think what you want is listen to the activate event of the view, and put some logic in there. And as a side note, the label doesn't have a option for store. It should be removed :)

Comment: because next step i want use json to dynamic to display on label and i want a clear MVC structure. i think in view must destory the structure

Comment: I think that you want to use a `container` instead and put the `json data array` as value on the `items` config :)

Comment: good idea! but i dont know how to pass json data from controller to view.do you have any demos.THX!!

Comment: We can go further over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131598/how-sencha-controller-get-json-data-from-store-and-then-pass-it-to-my-label-in-v

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added you controller file in app.js.   Try below code.

View code

```
xtype: 'label',
itemId: 'datalabel', // define item id here
//tpl:  '{store.get("data")},{store.get("earn")}',
store: 'interestsdata',
//tpl: ['总投资:{data},盈利:{earn}'],
html: 'hello',
flex: 1
```

controller code.

```
Ext.define('ylp2p.controller.viewdata',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        control: {
            'main #datalabel'{
                show: 'viewlabelFn'
            }
        }
    },    
    viewlabelFn: function(){
        alert('painted');
    }
});
```

Comment: yes,i have add controller in app.js.and i have try the code. it's not work.help.have any other ideas?